# incorrect output while concatenating query based on if condition yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I have a query as below

```
 $query= (new Query())->select(['title'])
               ->from('projects')
               ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'user AS u', 'p.user_ref_id=u.user_id')
               ->where('p.created_date >= STR_TO_DATE('.'"'.$fmonth.'"'.', "%d-%b-%Y")')
               ->andWhere('p.created_date <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('.'"'.$tmonth.'"'.', "%d-%b-%Y"), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')->all();
```

if I print the variable $query, I am getting below output

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => test project 1))
```

But if I write the below code

```
  $query= (new Query())->select(['title'])
               ->from('projects AS p')
               ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'user AS u', 'p.user_ref_id=u.user_id')
               ->where('p.created_date >= STR_TO_DATE('.'"'.$fmonth.'"'.', "%d-%b-%Y")')
               ->andWhere('p.created_date <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('.'"'.$tmonth.'"'.', "%d-%b-%Y"), INTERVAL 1 DAY)');
 if(!empty($status)){
  $query->andWhere(['p.project_status' => 1]);
 }
 $query->all();
```

When I print $query for above code. The output I am getting is

```
 yii\db\Query Object ( [select] => Array ( [0] => p.title [1]) [selectOption] => [distinct] => [from] => Array ( [0] => projects AS p ) [join] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => LEFT JOIN [1] => user AS u [2] => p.user_ref_id=u.user_id) )....
```

Why am I getting this object/array format when I try to split the query and concatenate. Is there any other way to execute to get in similar format as

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => test project 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly in first case you are printing the result of `all()` method while in the second one you are printing the `Query` object because there `all()` is not called on the printed variable but rather on the object itself so the result is lost.

If you print `$query->all()` in second case you will get what you want.